# Intersecting two tables with one common row elements in matlab

Tags: matlab, merge

I have two different tables (.csv files) as:

[image: Table 1 with five columns and 3296 number of rows]

[image: Table 2 with three columns and 3184 number of rows]

I need to merge these two tables in MATLAB, while intersecting first columns of both the tables. I want to make a new separate table with six number of columns(combined columns of both the tables) and number of rows will be equal to the number of intersecting elements of first column of both the tables.
 How should I do the intersection and merging of these two tables?

Comment: Looking at the tables, I noted the sub IDs are not unique to a table. Can you elaborate on that? My answer below assumes there each row has a unique sub ID.

Answer (score 0):

I'm proposing *an* answer. I'm not claiming it is the best answer. In fact, I think there are probably much faster ones! Also note that I do not have MATLAB in front of me right now and can't test this. There might be some mistakes.

First of all, read the .csv files into memory. In table 1, convert the first column into numeric data (currently, it looks like they are strings). After this step, you want to have two double matricies I'll call `table1` (which is 3296x5) and `table2` (which is 3184x3).

Second, (this is where it gets mildly interesting, step 1 was the boring stuff), is to find all IDs that are common to both tables. This can be done by calling `commonIDs=unique([table1(:,1) ; table2(:,1)])`.

Third, get the indicies of the common rows for table1. Then repeat for table2. This is done using the `ismember` function as follows:

```
goodEntries1=ismember(table1(:,1),commonIDs);
goodEntries2=ismember(table2(:,1),commonIDs);
```

Lastly, we extract data and combine to get a result. Note that I only include the ID column once:

```
result=[table1(goodEntries1,:) table2(goodEntries2,2:end)];
```

You will need to test this to make sure it is robust. I *think* that this will keep the right rows together, but depending on how `ismember` works, you might end up combining rows out of order (for instance, table1's ID=5 with table2's ID=6).

Comment: Thnaks for this answer. I tried using unique function for both the tables, but this function requires to have same number of rows in tables. Second I have used intersection function to take out the common subject Ids from the first column of the tables, which gives the common Ids existing in tables. I need to reject all the number of rows which are not common to both the tables.

Comment: Note that in the `unique` call I concatenate the rows together. Did you do this? It means the differing number of rows won't matter. Did you by chance leave out the semicolon?

Comment: Hello :) I have used the unique function exactly the way you mentioned.
Now i have following error :  commonIDs = unique([T1(:,1);T2(:,1)]);where T1 = (3184*3)table and T2 =(3296*5)table .
 ''All tables in the bracketed expression must have the same variable names.''

Comment: Hi, There was an error in he syntax, I did not specify the same variable name. After writing the code as the way you said, I followed that, now I am seeing the following error :                                                                                      result = [T1 (goodentries1,:) T2(goodentries,2:end)];
 result = [T1 (goodentries1,:) T2(goodentries,2:end)];
                           |
Error: Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.

Comment: @user2720470, You are right. You should be using `intersect` instead of `unique`. How much MATLAB experience do you have? Are you using the `table` command? It appears you might be. Is this for a school assignment? You must be missing a parenthesis or something.

Comment: it is part of my project. I do not have much experience in MATLAB. I have used intersect function to get the common IDs from both of the tables. Basically I need to Merge both the tables on the basis of the common elements of the first column. Can you please help me with the last command? I do not understand where am i missing the paranthesis..

Comment: Can you edit your question to add your current code. What you've posted has valid, balanced parentheses.

Comment: % intersecting first column common to both the tables
[C,ia,ib] = intersect(sub_ID_MSE,sub_id); 
goodentries1 = ismember (T2(:,1),CommonIDs);
goodentries2 = ismember (T1(:,1),CommonIDs);
result = [T1(goodentries1,:);T2(goodentries2,:)];
%error Row index exceeds table dimensions.

Comment: % intersecting first column common to both the tables
[C,ia,ib] = intersect(sub_ID_MSE,sub_id); 
goodentries1 = ismember (T2(:,1),CommonIDs);
goodentries2 = ismember (T1(:,1),CommonIDs);
result = [T1(goodentries1,:),T2(goodentries2,2:end)];
%error Row index exceeds table dimensions.